# Dynamic size of drawable xml

Tags: android

I've created xml for thumb image in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:bottom="5px"
        android:left="5px"
        android:right="5px"
        android:top="5px">
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval" >
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />


            <gradient
                android:endColor="#4DB9E6"
                android:startColor="#4DB9E6" />

            <size
                android:height="40dp"
                android:width="40dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Its working well.

i want diffferent size of thumb image xml.

How to achieve this dynamically?

Comment: see android.graphics.drawable.Drawable documentarion

Answer (score 2):

You can change the size of drawable by accessing it form

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thumb_xml);
```

and after that use:
setBound() Method.

but you can also make the Drawable at runtime through code and changing method parameters:

```
Drawable getThumb(int width,int height){
GradientDrawable thumb= new GradientDrawable(
             GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                 new int[] {Color.parseColor("#4DB9E6"),
                            Color.parseColor("#4DB9E6")});
                 thumb.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
                 thumb.setStroke(2,Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                 thumb.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40);

      return thumb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing

```
<size
    android:width="60dp"
    android:height="40dp" />
```

Or if you wish to change the size programmatically then try the below code

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_file_name);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()*0.5), 
                         (int)(drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()*0.5));
ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(drawable, 0, scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topSpace"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leftSpace"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rightSpace"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomSpace"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5" />
</LinearLayout>
```